# Problem encountered during Morphological transformation of MOG2 background reduction

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to reduce background noise and I choose to do MOG2 background reduction and further apply morphological transformation to get the best output.
But I got this error upon executing this code.

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fgbg=cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

while(cap.isOpened()):
    _,frame=cap.read()
    fgmask=fgbg.apply(frame)
    hsv=cv2.cvtColor(fgmask,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    
    lower_red=np.array([50,50,50])
    upper_red=np.array([180,255,255])
   
    mask=cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_red,upper_red)
    res=cv2.bitwise_and(fgmask,fgmask,mask=mask)

    #for morphological transformation
    kernel=np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    erosion=cv2.erode(mask,kernel,iterations=1)
    dilation=cv2.dilate(mask,kernel,iterations=1)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
    if k == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error:

```
hsv=cv2.cvtColor(fgmask,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) c:\users\appveyor\appdata\local\temp\1\pip-req-build-q0nmoxxv\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.simd_helpers.hpp:92: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::impl::`anonymous-namespace'::CvtHelper<struct cv::impl::`anonymous namespace'::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xd2b27d1f::Set<3,-1,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xd2b27d1f::Set<0,5,-1>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 1
```

After I got this error I understood that there might a problem writing cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV in cvtColor, but I don't know to solve this or the problem might be something else.
I also sense a problem (silly mistake) while writing  res=cv2.bitwise_and(fgmask,fgmask,mask=mask) , but I don't know to resolve this as I'm new to morphological transformation.

Please point out my mistake.
Thanks in advance

Comment: From the documentation on [`cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2.apply()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d7/d7b/classcv_1_1BackgroundSubtractorMOG2.html#a682adde901148d85450435e6cc0de4a1): `fgmask` *The output foreground mask as an 8-bit binary image.* You use `fgmask` as an input to `cvtColor` with color conversion code `BGR2HSV`, which must fail, since you have a single-channel image, not a three-channel image. So, what are you trying with the conversion to the HSV colorspace, if the mask is single-channel?

Comment: i know that BGR2HSV is wrong. I want to implement erosion and dilation on the output of MOG2 background reduction. So how do I do that?

Comment: Just apply [`erode`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaeb1e0c1033e3f6b891a25d0511362aeb), [`dilate`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga4ff0f3318642c4f469d0e11f242f3b6c), or something like [`morphologyEx`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f) directly on your `fgmask`. I still don't understand, why you're trying to do some kind of red color segmentation(?) on the `fgmask`.

Comment: that red color segmention was wrong, i realised that later but, i applied fgmask on erode, dilate and on morphologyEx now and there is little a lot of noise.[link](https://youtu.be/06vFemzgMuc) this is the video upon which I'm testing.

Comment: Also, a heads up, upon exploring, I used saliency and k-means then i applied MOG2. But the noise still persist and movement of the poeple isn't clear.